# How do I find the amount of atoms in a pure gas in a confined area?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atoms, ideal-gas

Say I have Argon gas in an area such as a cube with pressure around pressure between 10-5 and 10-3 Torr (pressure) at 25 degrees at 320 Kelvins . How do I find the amount of atoms in that cube? Any formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume it is an [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) and you know the volume of the cube, the temperature of the gas, and the pressure, you can calculate the number of atoms using the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law):

$PV=nRT$

Where `P` is pressure, `V` is volume, `n` is the nuber of moles, `R` is the [ideal gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_constant), and `T` is the temperature in Kelvin.